# expoのios.infoPlistが反映されない

Tags: javascript, ios, json, react-native

カメラロールにアクセスしようとした際に出現する、alert modalの文面を変えたいのですが、うまく変えられません

試したこと

```
"expo": {
"name": "留学コンパス.",
"icon": "./images/CompassPioneering-02.png",
"version": "1.0.2",
"slug": "ryugakuCompass",
"sdkVersion": "27.0.0",
"ios": {
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.ryugakucompass.ryugakuCompass",
  "infoPlist": {
    "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "ryugakuCompass access your photo library so that you can change your profile image."
  }
}
```

のようにapp.jsonを記述して、versionをあげ、

```
exp publish
```

や

```
exp build:ios
```

をターミナルで打ちましたが変化がありませんでした
[image: このような内容から変更できません]
どのようにすればmodal内の文章を変えることができるかわかる方がいらしたら教えていただきたいです

Answer (score 0):

Expoにおいてパーミッションダイアログの文言が変わらないということですね。
公式ドキュメントはご覧になられましたでしょうか。
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/app-stores.html#system-permissions-dialogs-on-ios

恐らくこちらも参考になるかと思われます。
https://qiita.com/h-sakano/items/00250f55b2370b8c6f4c

ビルドの際はbuild:iosなどでインスタントランはされましたでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

おそらくですが、質問者さんが挙動が変わっていないのを観測したのは、(iOS シミュレータないし、実機の上での) expo client アプリでの話ではないでしょうか？

これらパーミッションダイアログのメッセージは、「アプリごとに静的に決まっています」つまり、アプリをインストールした時点で、そのメッセージは固定されていて、その実、 expo client アプリの表示は、質問者さんの投稿画像のようなものになります。 app.json で指定して infoPlist にしたがってダイアログを表示されるには、作っているアプリを一つの iOS アプリとしてインストールする必要があります。

なので、ビルド成果物を testFlight で実機に載せるなどしてみると、果たして正しく設定できているかが、確認できると思います。